Return of a mobile robot to skipped places (nav2, opennav_coverage)
I am planning an autonomous vacuum cleaner application in which I will use opennav_coverage to cover the full area. I expect a situation where the robot will miss part of the area due to an obstacle on the road (a person or something left on the ground). Will nav2_stack make it possible to return to such missed places after completing the trajectory? Do I need to create a module manually for this?
I am using ros2 humble for this.
